# How do I delete holidays from a Pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series with two columns and lots of rows like:

```
r = 
    1-10-2010   3.4
    1-11-2010   4.5
    1-12-2010   3.7
    ...         ...
```

What I'd like to do is to remove days of the week not in a custom week. So to remove Fridays and Saturdays, do something like this:

```
r = amazingfunction(r, ('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', Thu'))
r =
    1-10-2010   3.4
    1-11-2010   4.5
    1-12-2010   3.7
    1-13-2010   3.4
    1-14-2010   4.1
    1-17-2010   4.5
    1-18-2010   3.7
    ...         ...
```

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`dt.dayofweek`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.dayofweek.html) and [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to filter the df, here Friday and Saturday are `4,5` respectively, we negate the boolean mask using `~`:

```
In [12]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2015,1,1), dt.datetime(2015,2,1))})
df['dayofweek'] = df['dates'].dt.dayofweek
df

Out[12]:
        dates  dayofweek
0  2015-01-01          3
1  2015-01-02          4
2  2015-01-03          5
3  2015-01-04          6
4  2015-01-05          0
5  2015-01-06          1
6  2015-01-07          2
7  2015-01-08          3
8  2015-01-09          4
9  2015-01-10          5
10 2015-01-11          6
11 2015-01-12          0
12 2015-01-13          1
13 2015-01-14          2
14 2015-01-15          3
15 2015-01-16          4
16 2015-01-17          5
17 2015-01-18          6
18 2015-01-19          0
19 2015-01-20          1
20 2015-01-21          2
21 2015-01-22          3
22 2015-01-23          4
23 2015-01-24          5
24 2015-01-25          6
25 2015-01-26          0
26 2015-01-27          1
27 2015-01-28          2
28 2015-01-29          3
29 2015-01-30          4
30 2015-01-31          5
31 2015-02-01          6

In [13]:
df[~df['dates'].dt.dayofweek.isin([4,5])]

Out[13]:
        dates  dayofweek
0  2015-01-01          3
3  2015-01-04          6
4  2015-01-05          0
5  2015-01-06          1
6  2015-01-07          2
7  2015-01-08          3
10 2015-01-11          6
11 2015-01-12          0
12 2015-01-13          1
13 2015-01-14          2
14 2015-01-15          3
17 2015-01-18          6
18 2015-01-19          0
19 2015-01-20          1
20 2015-01-21          2
21 2015-01-22          3
24 2015-01-25          6
25 2015-01-26          0
26 2015-01-27          1
27 2015-01-28          2
28 2015-01-29          3
31 2015-02-01          6
```

**EDIT**

As your data is a `Series` your dates are your index so the following should work:

```
r[~r.index.dayofweek.isin([4,5])]
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do this without using a DataFrame and only a series?

Comment: don't understand it will still work, for instance in your question you state a Series with 2 columns, this is impossible, a Series is only a single column, are your dates your index?

Comment: When I run `print type(r)`, I get `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`, so I assume it's a series. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes but that means the dates are your index: `r[~r.index.dayofweek.isin([4,5])]` should work

Comment: Okay that works, and my series had additional errors. Why use r.index.dayofweek...? Why index?

Comment: Because your date values are your index

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!